# A heap queue in Dyalog APL

Tags: heap, apl

I am learning Dyalog APL. I implemented a binary heap, which seems to work. How could I make it look more like APL (and less like Python)?

```
⎕io←0
heappush←{(⍺,⍵)siftdown 0(≢⍺)}

heappop←{
 heap←⍵
 last←⊃¯1↑heap ⋄ rest←¯1↓heap
 0=≢rest:rest last
 r←heap[0]
 (((last@0)rest)siftup 0)r
}

siftdown←{
 heap←⍺
 start pos←⍵
 item←pos⌷heap
 newpos←{
  ⍵≤start:⍵
  parentpos←⌊(⍵-1)÷2
  parent←parentpos⌷heap
  item<parent:∇ parentpos⊣heap[⍵]←parent
  ⍵
 }pos
 (item@newpos)heap
}

siftup←{
  heap←⍺
  p←{
   pos←⍵
   chp←1+2×pos
   chp≥≢heap:pos
   rpos←1+chp
   chp←((rpos<≢heap)∧~heap[chp]<heap[rpos])⊃chp rpos
   heap[pos]←heap[chp]
   ∇ chp
  }⍵
  heap[p]←⍺[⍵]
  heap siftdown ⍵ p
 }

heap←0 1 2 5 6 8 9
heappop heap

┌→────────────────┐
│ ┌→──────────┐   │
│ │1 5 2 9 6 8│ 0 │
│ └~──────────┘   │
└∊────────────────┘

heap heappush 3
┌→──────────────┐
│0 1 2 3 6 8 9 5│
└~──────────────┘
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How could I make it look more like APL (and less like Python)?

Assuming you mean "in a more functional and less imperative way" by this line,

### I don't think you can largely achieve that, for a good reason.

Basically, the array-based heap (and other common algorithms you see on algorithm textbooks) is designed for imperative languages. Translating it into a language *whose main strength isn't imperative* makes the code feel awkward and unfitting. It may also lead to code whose time complexity is actually worse than designed. [See how it looks like when a similar algorithm is written in Haskell.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/958588/4595904)

APL is not 100% functional, but definitely is more functional than imperative (especially when you mainly use dfns). If you want, search for "functional algorithms" and try implementing those. In the case of a heap, [leftist tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leftist_tree) isn't too complex, and supports one more \$O(\log n)\$ operation (heap merge) compared to an imperative binary heap. You can check out a [nice illustration](http://typeocaml.com/2015/03/12/heap-leftist-tree/) too.

### But you can still improve some parts of the code.

#### Improvement in the algorithm

- Use `⎕IO←1` instead.

Array-based heap uses 0-based indexing by default, so the parent-child relationship is slightly awkward:

$$
\begin{align}
\text{left child}&=1+2\times\text{parent} \\
\text{right child}&=2+2\times\text{parent} \\
\text{parent}&=\Bigl\lfloor \frac{\text{child} - 1}2 \Bigr\rfloor
\end{align}
$$

If you use 1-based indexing instead, it becomes slightly cleaner:

$$
\begin{align}
\text{left child}&=2\times\text{parent} \\
\text{right child}&=1+2\times\text{parent} \\
\text{parent}&=\Bigl\lfloor \frac{\text{child}}2 \Bigr\rfloor
\end{align}
$$

I don't have other better ideas to utilize the strengths of APL, due to the underlying algorithm being purely imperative.

#### General tips for writing APL code

- Let the right argument of dyadic functions be the primary one (i.e. the heap).
- If you see a negation of a comparison (e.g. `~heap[chp]<heap[rpos]`), use a single equivalent function (e.g. `heap[chp]≥heap[rpos]`).
- Prefer concatenation (e.g. `0,≢⍺`) over stranding (e.g. `0(≢⍺)`) when you concatenate two scalars.
- Try not to modify existing variable's contents (e.g. avoid `chp←((rpos<≢heap)∧~heap[chp]<heap[rpos])⊃chp rpos` which refers to `chp` and then modifies it) when it isn't essential in implementing the algorithm. Try to choose a separate and meaningful name instead.
- Parenthesize stranding assignments (e.g. `(start pos)←⍵` instead of `start pos←⍵`).
- Consider following a [naming convention](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/239843/182436), and a little more descriptive names. (e.g. I can't easily see what `chp` stands for.)
- Consider adding comments to each function which briefly describe the input(s) and the output.

Comment: Thank you! I made a Leftist Tree following your suggestion, and it does indeed look much better: https://gist.github.com/xpqz/c10b3009a68f9ffdc84c2fb09b44302a

Comment: @xpqz Great job :) If you want further feedback, you can post a separate question with your new piece of code.

Comment: New question here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/240089/leftist-tree-in-dyalog-apl-can-it-be-made-more-compact-idiomatic